# reading bytes with ifstream

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm relatively new to c++, and have some issues with ifstream. All I want to do is to read the file byte by byte, however, reading always fails in the middle of the file. My code:

```
void read(ifstream&f)
{
    unsigned char b;
    for (int i=0;;++i)
    {
        if(!f.good())
        {
            cout<<endl<<"error at: "<<i;
            return;
        }
        f>>b; // b=f.get(); and f.read(&b, 1); doesnt work either
        cout<<b;
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

It reads the first few hundred bytes correctly, then the rest of the file is skipped. Something wrong about buffering? What did I do wrong?

EDIT:

I just found out something that might be the cause: in the file I use CRLF line endings (2 bytes), but all the above methods return only LF, so at the end of each line i is incresed only by one, however there are 2 bytes in the file. So my question is: how can I obtain both CR and LF separately?

Comment: Do you get the "error at:" report? Are you reading a binary file or a text file? If the former, have you opened the ifstream in binary mode?

Comment: `cout << b` may not print some of the characters, if they're not printable characters.

Comment: The file contains only printable chars.

Comment: @Alex Yes, I get the error report, but earlier than the file really ends.

Comment: @Dave: If the file only contains printable chars (and no '\0') I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you post the file somewhere, or an extract of the file that exhibits the issue?

Comment: Define *reading always fails*.

Comment: Does the file contain a 0x1A or 0x04 or 0x0c bytes? Windows & DOS machines are known to stop reading, when in not **binary** mode, when a 0x1A value (end of file) is read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by opening the file in binary mode (thanks Alex for drawing my attention to it).

Seems like the CR character messes up both ifstream and cout, that caused my confusion, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Why not just accept Beta's answer? This is not fair.

Comment: @qed I think I made it clear both in my question edit and in a comment under Beta's answer, that his solution doesn't work. Please read more carefully next time.

Answer (score 23):

try

```
f.read(&b, 1);
```

Both `<<` and `get()` are intended for *text*, not binary data.

Comment: @Dave, could you give us a minimal file that causes the error? Also, please show us how you prepare the `ifstream`.

Comment: @Dave : Are you opening the stream in binary mode? (If you're not, you should be.)